# How to execute command in subproject directory for Gradle multiproject build?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle multiproject build, with each subproject in separate git repositories. In the build.gradle of the root project I am trying to define a task for all subprojects which will execute some git commands for each project. However, the working directory of the task is always that of the root project.

How can I change workingDir depending on current subproject executing the task?

```
subprojects {
    task someTask{
        def p1 = 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'.execute()
        p1.waitFor()
        println p1.exitValue()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the Gradle [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) task, which uses the project directory as the default working directory. The task also has an option to change the working directory explicitly (`workingDir`).

```java
subprojects {
    task someTask(type:Exec) {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'
        doLast {
            logger.lifecycle('Exit value was ' + execResult.exitValue)
        }
    }
}
```